# CGI self-referenced URLs use HTTP instead of HTTPS when using AWS ELB

Tags: apache, perl, nginx, https, amazon-elb

I have a Perl HTTPS application which runs behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). The HTTPS is terminated by the ELB, which then forwards the requests as HTTP to my instances.

The issue is that, because the instance itself is accessed via HTTP, when I use the CGI module to generate self-referencing URL's, they incorrectly use HTTP instead of HTTPS, so form POSTs fail.

GET request are ok because they're redirected, but anything that uses POST doesn't work.

If I check my CGI environment variables, I have the following...

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT = 443
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = https
REQUEST_SCHEME = http
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
```

The CGI module is presumably using `REQUEST_SCHEME` or `SERVER_PROTOCOL` to determine that the URLs should use `http://`.

Is there some way I can fudge the environment variables at the Apache or NGINX level to convince CGI that the site is in fact HTTPS?

Comment: Can you give an example of Perl code that uses a CGI function to create a self-referencing URL?

Comment: It's using `SERVER_PROTOCOL`. https://metacpan.org/source/LEEJO/CGI-4.32/lib/CGI.pm#L3157 – if this always runs in the https world, you could just subclass CGI or monkey-patch that function to always return `https`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively simple way to do it.

I just SetEnv HTTPS 'on' in the Apache config. The CGI module is now satisfied that it's HTTPS, so creates URLs accordingly.

I set the other environment variables to match just to be safe, but it just seems to be HTTPS that CGI uses.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/blob/72ce8e187a95d69cc3e417f022475cc0d9f744f5/lib/CGI.pm#L3140) is the part of [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) that is responsible for determining if `HTTPS` is being used:

```
sub https {
    my ($self,$parameter) = self_or_CGI(@_);
    if ( defined($parameter) ) {
        $parameter =~ tr/-a-z/_A-Z/;
        if ( $parameter =~ /^HTTPS(?:_|$)/ ) {
            return $ENV{$parameter};
        }
        return $ENV{"HTTPS_$parameter"};
    }
    return wantarray
        ? grep { /^HTTPS(?:_|$)/ } keys %ENV
        : $ENV{'HTTPS'};
}
```

[`protocol`](https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/blob/72ce8e187a95d69cc3e417f022475cc0d9f744f5/lib/CGI.pm#L3157) consults the return value of this method:

```
return 'https' if uc($self->https()) eq 'ON';
```

So, your solution of `SetEnv HTTPS on` would work.

However, if you wanted your program to respect `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`, you could monkey patch CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw();

{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    my $original_https = \&CGI::https;

    *CGI::https = sub {
        goto $original_https unless my $proto = $ENV{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO};
        return 'on' if lc($proto) eq 'https';
        return 'off';
    };
}

my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->self_url, "\n";
```

```
$ HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO=https ./monkey.pl
https://localhost:80
$ ./monkey.pl
http://localhost
```

Of course, this points out that `CGI` now appends the port number, and because it does not pay attention to `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT`, it likely gets that wrong as well. If I am not mistaken, for that you'd need to monkey patch `virtual_port`.